# MSSQL sp_dropextendedproperty are not permitted

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am new to `MSSQL`, and I am trying to move db from one server to another.
I am using `SQLCMD` to restore the DB
However, I am stuck on the following line, (script has many like these I just took one for sake of example)

on running `SQLCMD -S servername\SQLEXPRESS -U myuser -P somepassword@1234 -i C:\1.sql -o C:\1.txt` which has following code

```sql
USE [MoodleNew]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_dropextendedproperty 
    @name=N'MS_SSMA_SOURCE' , 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA',
    @level0name=N'my_schema', 
    @level1type=N'TABLE',
    @level1name=N'my_table_name'
GO
```

I am getting following error

`Object is invalid. Extended properties are not permitted on 'my_schema.my_table_name', or the object does not exist.`

No idea what the issue is, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the `my_schema.my_table_name` table exist in the `MoodleNew` database?

Comment: Given your inexperience, why do this at all? Just take a backup of your source database and then restore it.